# Oracle SQL crazy subqueries across 4 tables

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

Here are the relations:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
  fname    varchar2(15) not null, 
  minit    varchar2(1),
  lname    varchar2(15) not null,
  ssn      char(9),
  bdate    date,
  address  varchar2(30),
  sex      char,
  salary   number(10,2),
  superssn char(9),
  dno      number(4),
  primary key (ssn),
  foreign key (superssn) references employee(ssn),
  foreign key (dno) references department(dnumber)
);

CREATE TABLE department (
  dname        varchar2(15) not null,
  dnumber      number(4),
  mgrssn       char(9) not null, 
  mgrstartdate date,
  primary key (dnumber),
  unique (dname),
  foreign key (mgrssn) references employee(ssn)
);

CREATE TABLE dept_locations (
  dnumber   number(4),
  dlocation varchar2(15), 
  primary key (dnumber,dlocation),
  foreign key (dnumber) references department(dnumber)
);

CREATE TABLE project (
  pname      varchar2(15) not null,
  pnumber    number(4),
  plocation  varchar2(15),
  dnum       number(4) not null,
  primary key (pnumber),
  unique (pname),
  foreign key (dnum) references department(dnumber)
);

CREATE TABLE works_on (
  essn   char(9),
  pno    number(4),
  hours  number(4,1),
  primary key (essn,pno),
  foreign key (essn) references employee(ssn),
  foreign key (pno) references project(pnumber)
);
```

Q: Find the names and addresses of all employees who work on at least one project located in Houston but whose department has no location in Houston.

Here is my query:

```
select fname, minit, lname, address
from employee
where dno=
(select dnumber from dept_locations where dlocation<>'Houston' and dnumber=
(select dno from employee where ssn=
(select essn from works_on where pno=
(select pnumber from project where plocation='Houston'))))
```

But it did not compile and returned this error:

```
    ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

Please help!

Comment: `dno` can't = multiple rows. Try using `IN` instead of `=` and use `OR` between the subs

Comment: Are you really going to make a post for every question on your assignment?

Comment: Only the ones I couldn't figure out. I finished the remaining 90% on my own. Sorry if you are bothered by them.

Comment: @DanJ to be fair, the knowledge barrier to getting a job writing Oracle code is very low nowadays -- you barely need Google skills to look up syntax or examples, or guidance on specific issues. You just post anything vaguely difficult to Stackoverflow. Dowvoting questions is the way to go with these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select fname, minit, lname, address
from employee
where dno in
(select dnumber from dept_locations where dlocation<>'Houston') and ssn in
(select essn from works_on where pno in
(select pnumber from project where plocation='Houston'))))
```

Comment: select pnumber from project where plocation='Houston' and check it gives the right pnumber that u requried....bcz there is no other reason to give incorrect result

Comment: Yes, running that query alone did give me the correct result.

Comment: (select dno from employee where ssn in
(select essn from works_on where pno  here u write ssn in one place and essn in other place...why?

Comment: select pnumber from project where plocation='Houston'
(select dnumber from dept_locations where dlocation<>'Houston'
first u are selecting palce only houston...and than u select the place that is not hpuston..thats why..u r gettting blank result right....

Comment: I am trying to move the order of the subqueries around as per your suggestion. Will report back with more problems. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Amit, I tried doing it your way by querying for where dlocation<>'Houston' first, but that method is not workable because in the actual data there are departments that are located in several locations. Suppose dept 5 has offices in Houston and Dallas, while it's true running that query will filter out the 5 Houston row, but the 5 Dallas one will still come up. The question wants me to filter out all the departments that have an office in Houston.

Comment: Worked wonderfully. Used a different approach last night and got the same answer as you. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Your call "where dno=" expects a single result.

try

```
 where dno in (select...)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  fname,
  minit,
  lname,
  address
from
  employee
where
  exists (
    select null
    from   works_on join project on (works_on.pno = project.pnumber)
    where  works_on.essn  = employee.ssn and
           not exists (
             select null
             from   dept_locations
             where  dept_locations.dlocation = project.plocation))
```

Other comments:

1. The lack of consistency in table and column naming is very irritating to work with. DNO and DNUMBER?
2. Using a social security number as a key value is a stupid error. It's stupid because people's SSN's are private and should be protected, and it's an error because it is not immutable.